# Apollo server 2.0. Type "Upload" not found in document

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

How to replicate:

server.js

```
const { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema, gql } = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql`
type Mutation {
    uploadAvatar(upload: Upload!): String!
}
`;
const resolvers = {
    Mutation: {
        uploadAvatar(root, args, context, info) {
            return 'test';
        }
    }
  };

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^2.0.0-rc.6",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2"
  }
```

On node server.js we get the following error:

> Type "Upload" not found in document.

Given the latest version of apollo server, am I supposed to add anything else to the query? According to [this](https://blog.apollographql.com/file-uploads-with-apollo-server-2-0-5db2f3f60675) tutorial and few other sources that I currently cannot recall, one does not need to do anything more than just write Upload and it should work fine. Am I missing anything?

Comment: It seems it should work properly: 
```
Apollo Server 2.0 automatically adds the Upload scalar to the schema, so any existing declaration of scalar Upload in the schema should be removed.
```

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of ways I've fixed this, in the example on the apollo docs:

> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/guides/file-uploads.html

you can see he doesn't use `makeExecutableSchema` but passed the resolvers and schema to the apollo server this stopped the error:

> Type "Upload" not found in document.

If you want to use `makeExecutableSchema` then import the scalar

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  scalar Upload

  type Mutation {
    uploadAvatar(upload: Upload!): String!
  }
  type Query {
    ping: String
  }
`;
```

> https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-examples/blob/master/api/schema.mjs

if you look at some of the example source code for the at blog post you can see he uses a scalar

The reason it wasn't being added automatically is

> Scalar Upload
>   The Upload type automatically added to the schema by Apollo Server resolves an object containing the following:

- stream
- filename
- mimetype
- encoding

**UPDATE:** Apollo have made it clearer that when you use makeExecutableSchema you need to define the scalar for it to work

> In a situation where a schema is set manually using makeExecutableSchema and passed to the ApolloServer constructor using the schema params, add the Upload scalar to the type definitions and Upload to the resolver

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/guides/file-uploads.html#File-upload-with-schema-param